# The use of the gerund in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Sentence:
"Having started at the position of a teacher, I was later promoted to holding the role of the coordinator of the school."

I wonder if this sentence is correct.

The idea is that "holding the role" is a promotional responsibility and that is why I prefer using the gerund. Thoughts please?

Comment: I'd say yes. You're "promoted to something" and this something is here "holding the role of the coordinator", simply meaning "promoted to the coordinator". Might be a little clumsy though, but I guess native speaker can elaborate on this.

Answer (score 2):

it is awkward to speak of being promoted to “holding”, or any other verbal construction: one is customarily promoted to a position, not an action.

In any case, I would express this much more simply:

> I started as a teacher and was later promoted to Coordinator of the school.
>    (*But if you held intervening positions I would replace* later *with* eventually.)

*Position*, *hold* and *role* are entirely superfluous: their sense is expressed in the narrative sequence. I have capitalized Coordinator on the assumption that this is the actual title you bore, which is what should go here.